# Why am I getting an error in list comprehension statement?

Tags: python, list, syntax-error, list-comprehension

```
transfers = [['owen', 'susan', '10'], ['owen', 'robert', '10'], ['owen','drew', '10'], ['fred', 'owen', '20']]

people = ['drew', 'fred', 'owen', 'robert', 'susan']

bals = [0]*len(people)

for p in people:

    bals[k for k in range(len(people))] = [i[2] for i in transfers if p in i]
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why am I getting this error?

i[2] for i in transfers should be the numbers in the lists of "transfers", and I only want it to be the numbers from the lists that contain the name of the certain person (p) in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
for i, p in enumerate(people):
    bals[i] = [t[2] for t in transfers if p in t]
```

Or,

`bals = [[t[2] for t in transfers if p in t] for p in people]`

Your code does not work because list subscription does not accept list comprehension.

In addition, list subscription does accept `generator`. Putting list comprehension inside parenthesis makes a generator. A correct code in terms of **syntax** could be `bals[(k for k in range(len(people)))]` where in the middle it is a  `generator` object. But generator still **won't work** with list and therefore is a `TypeError`.